# How to implement a Rust constructor that's parameterized on an integer?

Tags: rust

I'd like to construct an object that's parameterized on an integer. Tried the following:

```
struct Alpha<T> {
    num: T,
}

impl<T: Integer> Alpha<T> {
    fn new() -> Alpha<T> {
        Alpha { num: 0 }
    }
}
```

and got the error:

```
11 |         Alpha { num: 0 }
   |                      ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable
```

The code is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=51490f46878fe8d66f92c1f63df61919&version=stable). What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong?

This is:

```
struct Foo;
impl Integer for Foo { … }
Alpha::<Foo>::new() // This should work as `Foo: Integer` and that's
                    // the only condition on `Alpha::new`.
                    // But it would need to create a instance
                    // of `Foo` from `0`.
                    // But the compiler has no idea how to do that!
```

`num::Integer` implies `num::Zero`, [you can just use that](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=2810523444f4036b6c6481bda0c4dd91&version=stable):

```
impl<T: Integer> Alpha<T> {
    fn new() -> Alpha<T> {
        Alpha { num: Zero::zero() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don’t follow the Foo example but I’m gathering it’s less straightforward from what I’m used to in Haskell.

Comment: I've tried to explain the `Foo` example better.